# CustomScrollView slivers with snap and enter-always behavior

Tags: android, flutter, scroll, sliverappbar

In my Flutter app, I have a `CustomScrollView` with various slivers. I need to insert two widgets at the top of the list that would behave in a manner similar to views in Android's native `AppBarLayout` with `scroll|snap|enterAlways` and `noScroll` flags respectively.

This means that

- the first widget 1) **snaps** (it has no intermediate scroll
  position and is either entirely visible or entirely hidden) and 2) **reveals itself on any downward scroll** regardless of the current scroll
  position (in fact, this is the effect I'm most interesed in);
- the second widget doesn't scroll and acts more like a sticky header.

Below is a visualization and a sketch of the layout in native XML, with irrelevant properties left out:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <AppBarLayout>
        <TextView
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|enterAlways" />

        <TextView
            app:layout_scrollFlags="noScroll" />
    </AppBarLayout>

    <RecyclerView
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

I know there is a `SliverAppBar` but I'm not sure I can apply it to my use case. [Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html) says that this widget is

> An app bar [that] consists of a toolbar and potentially other widgets,
> such as a TabBar and a FlexibleSpaceBar.

First of all I don't have a toolbar, and secondly `SliverAppBar` in general doesn't seem like a direct counterpart of `AppBarLayout`.

Is there a built-in way to achieve the desired behavior in Flutter with `CustomScrollView`?

Thanks